# Python 2: class scope

Tags: class, python-2.7, oop, python-decorators

I wrote a decorator that will change to a user supplied directory, execute a function and then return to the original directory.

Now I'm trying to use this decorator within a class and have a scoping problem.  Here's an example.

```
class SampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, working_dir):
        self.dir = working_dir

    @preserve_cwd(self.dir)
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass
```

Python will return **NameError: name 'self' is not defined**.

Is there a good way to define attributes in the __init__ method of a class and be able to use them in the class name space?  Thanks for your help.

Edit:

Comment requested the decorator definition.

```
def preserve_cwd(working_dir):
    """Decorator: Return to the current working directory after function call.

    :param str working_dir: path to working directory
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            original_dir = os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(working_dir)

            try:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                os.chdir(original_dir)

        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Comment: Why did you not post the decorator definition? I sure would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator is outside of the method, not inside, that's why self is not defined.

You can try a piece of code like this:

```
#define the decorator, it accepts the function to be wrapped
def dec(f):
    #it returns a function that takes some arguments
    def wrapper(*args):
        s, = args  #take the first one (it should be self)
        print(s.dir) #do something
        result = f(*args) #call the wrapped function
        print(s.dir) #do something
        return result #return the result of the function
    #and returns the wrapped function
    return wrapper

class A:
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.dir = dir

    @dec
    def p(self):
        print "P!"

a = A("ABC")
a.p()
```

You should get "ABC" printed above and below "P!". This way you can change the environment as you need and then bring it back to the previous state.